# Как скопировать div с последующим изменением?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как скопировать div,  чтобы можно было заменить содержимое тега span на то, что будет введено в input?

```html
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='название товара' value='' />
<input type='submit' />
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ffffff/ffffff.jpg">
  <div class="info">
    <span>Тэн 18Мм 1750Вт Kawai</span>
    <p>уточнить цену</p>
    <button>05478987488</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: какой объект? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function copyDiv() {
  var src = document.querySelector(".card");
  var dst = document.createElement("div");
  dst.className = "card";
  dst.innerHTML = src.innerHTML;
  dst.querySelector("span").textContent = document.querySelector("input[type=text]").value;
  src.parentNode.appendChild(dst);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='название товара' value='' />
<input type='submit' onclick="copyDiv()"/>
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ffffff/ffffff.jpg">
  <div class="info">
    <span>Тэн 18Мм 1750Вт Kawai</span>
    <p>уточнить цену</p>
    <button>05478987488</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `dst.querySelector("span").textContent = document.querySelector("input[type=text]").value;`

Comment: @Alex согласен )